# How to configure 4 spaces per tab in komodo for python?

Tags: python, komodo

I am using komodo-edit (Komodo Edit, version 8.5.0, build 13638, platform macosx) to write python code. Whenever I press the 'tab' key I want the editor to insert 4 spaces. The preference looks like this:

[image]

To me this configuration looks fine. But when I press 'tab' in the editor, it looks like two 4-space wide tabs are inserted! What is wrong? How to configure komodo-edit in oder it inserts 4 spaces whenever I press the 'tab' key?

Note: I am using this on a mac. Maybe its a mac issue...?

Comment: Do you have to use tab? I mean, can you just type 4 spaces manually? Or maybe tab just looks like that and actually works the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install komodo-edit 11. Seems to be a bug in version 8.5

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not a mac issue. You just need to uncheck the `Force shallow indent at string start` and try again.

Comment: No, I have still the same issue

Comment: Ouch.Then, is it possible for you to export your preferences? I will try it in my local and see what is wrong with it.

Comment: Maybe there is another usable python editor available for macs?

Comment: bad news, it didn't happen in my place using your preferences. I am using hackintosh though. But, I don't think it matters that much. As for another python editor, you always can count on vim. Or, pycharm is nice (I use IDEA with python plugin on my daily job)